# How to escape the Ajax response sent from a jsp file while using tab-lib

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery, jspinclude

I am having a jsp page. Inside which i import a jspf file. In the jspf file, i have used tab-libs similar to this

```
<a href="javascript:moveToPage('<c:out value="${requestScope.PREVIOUS_LINK}"/>')">
<img align="absmiddle" src="images/<c:out value='${selectedTheme}'/>/previous.gif" width="23" height="14" alt="Previous" title="<fmt:message key="jsp.imagetitle.Previous"/>" border="0"></a>
```

The jsp file looks like

```
<div id="someId">
<%@ include file='jspf/myNewPage.jspf'%>
</div>
```

This jsp page is called to another jsp page using ajax and filled in a div using

```
$('#divid').html(response.responseText);
```

When i get the output on the screen, it shows some html tags printed and the image in img tag is not printed.

Comment: how does the generated html code in `response.responseText` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see HTML tags, then someone/something in your code converts the HTML to text (i.e. it escapes all special characters like `<` to `&lt;`, etc.) You should see this when looking at the HTML source code in your browser.

This looks odd to me:

```
<a href="javascript:moveToPage('<c:out value="${requestScope.PREVIOUS_LINK}"/>')">
```

`<` isn't allowed inside of an element, so this should either give an error or the code you pasted above isn't a 1:1 copy from your jspf file.

This would be valid:

```
<a href="javascript:moveToPage('&lt;c:out...
```

but wouldn't execute the `c:out` anymore.

Use [fn:escapeXml()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) instead:

```
<a href="javascript:moveToPage('${fn:escapeXml(requestScope.PREVIOUS_LINK)}'">
```